# Display image using Windows API

Tags: winapi, lazarus

I am using a looping primitive code to output a test image:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LP1, LP2: TLogPen;
  hp1, hp2: THandle;
  hdcv: Handle;
  i: integer;
begin
  LP1.lopnColor:=$FF0000;
  LP1.lopnStyle:=0;
  LP1.lopnWidth:=Classes.Point(1,0);
  LP2.lopnColor:=$FFFFFF;
  LP2.lopnStyle:=0;
  LP2.lopnWidth:=Classes.Point(1,0);
  hp1:=Windows.CreatePenIndirect(Windows.LOGPEN(LP1));
  hp2:=Windows.CreatePenIndirect(Windows.LOGPEN(LP2));

  hdcv:=Canvas.Handle;
  for i:=1 to 1000 do
    begin
      SelectObject(hdcv, hp1);
      Windows.MoveToEx(hdcv, 10+2*i, 10, nil);
      Windows.LineTo(hdcv, 50+2*i, 50);
      Sleep(100);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      SelectObject(hdcv, hp2);
      Windows.MoveToEx(hdcv, 10+2*i+1, 10, nil);
      Windows.LineTo(hdcv, 50+2*i+1, 50);
      Sleep(100);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;

  Windows.DeleteObject(hp1);
  Windows.DeleteObject(hp2);
end;
```

The problem is that when the mouse is on the button (Button1), lines output is intermittent. As if drawing takes place in some kind of buffer, and after some time it is displayed on the form. [I recorded a video](https://youtu.be/ATuPF_Cxi54). I am using Windows 7 and Lazarus 1.6.4. Can someone explain this graphics behavior?

Comment: I can not test with Windows 7 at the moment, and I only speculate here. I think Win 7 introduced some animation to indicate hot status (kind of pulsating fill color when mouse is on the button). Perhaps that has higher priority (in a thight loop), than the display output of your program. What if you try with other kind of buttons, maybe `TSpeedButton` or something else, just for comparison.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is (probably some kind of modal message loop the system spins up), but the solution certainly is to not put any rendering code into a button click handler. Have your `WM_PAINT` handler (however that is exposed in Delphi or VCL) do the painting. That's what it's for.

Comment: @TomBrunberg  Thanks for the answer. I tried using TSpeedButton. The output of lines in this case is performed correctly. One more observation. If I run the screen recording program, the output of lines is also carried out correctly. Therefore, the attached video was recorded using a smartphone camera.

Answer (score 0):

During the sleep, windows repaint messages can't operate. So it is possible that the repaint only happens on the processmessages stage.

The best solution is to rewrite this asynchronously using a timer.

To test the hypothesis you could replace the sleep-application.processes with a more fine grained solution like

So  instead of

```
 sleep(100);   
 Application.ProcessMessages;
```

we replace it with

```
for y:=1 to 10 do
 begin
   sleep(10);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
 end;
```

Somewhat nicer is a solution like this (pseudocode only):

```
 startticks:=gettickcount64; // startticks = int64
 while (gettickcount64-startticks)<100 do
    begin
      sleep(10);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
```

which accounts better for the time spent in Application.Processmessages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using: for y:=1 to 10 do .... It had no effect. Line output is still interrupted.

Comment: It's probably the hoovering triggering some modal mode that somehow inhibits the message pump, like the other comments say. Btw, 1.6.4 is a very old version.